# Getting position of Chrome's pageAction icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to get the ***position*** information of Chrome extension's pageAction icon?

For example:

[image]

icon position **3**, icon position **2**, and icon position **1**.

I need to know which *position* the user has chosen to place my icon at.

Comment: No, but why would you need to know?

Comment: Try making a window screenshot via [chrome.desktopCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) and analyze the pixels.

Comment: @DanielHerr, For beauty aligning of several page content.

Comment: @wOxxOm, For some reason the [desktopCapture sample code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#desktop-capture-example) doesn't work on my side. The "capture screen" doesn't seem to change from blank to anything. Does the sample code work on your system?

Comment: Seems to be working: https://puu.sh/tVMhP/f1d06c0e15.png